# How to filter debug output window on visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How do i remove or filter this kind of message?

This is very annoying and keeps displaying the whole time I cant understand why.
Im using visual studio 2019 c++.

[image: Is safer to exit and terminate or stuck the code in a "fake" while loop? When x condition doesn't meet i will]

After reading this line of code:
`MessageBox(g_hWnd, string.data(), L"", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_APPLMODAL | MB_TOPMOST);`

The message always is displayed:

```
windows\dwm\dwmapi\attribute.cpp(105)\dwmapi.dll!00007FFBE41B1940: (caller: 000000018000E820) LogHr(1) tid(83b8) 80070006 Identificador inválido.
```

But if I remove `MB_ICONSTOP` and use only:
`MessageBox(g_hWnd, string.data(), L"", MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND | MB_APPLMODAL | MB_TOPMOST);`it does not display.

It is also displayed by other things that I didn't know.

Some google:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a5a145a-c13d-4898-bb61-a5baadc9332f/why-am-i-getting-hundreds-of-weird-messages-in-debug-output-window?forum=vcgeneral

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/258494/windowsdwmdwmapiattributecpp92dwmapidll72ed3cf4-ca.html

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a5a145a-c13d-4898-bb61-a5baadc9332f/why-am-i-getting-hundreds-of-weird-messages-in-debug-output-window?forum=vcgeneral
But this message doesnt help in anything.

Comment: Not sure there is much you can do, many debug build binaries log verbose, just in case it is useful, given that they don't provide the source.

Comment: You should post the error messages as text too...

Comment: When will that message be displayed? (install <regional> windows, install visual Studio, build project, something like that, I guess?

Comment: I have added more info.

Comment: @Guto I can only suggest you upvote [Missing a way to filter debug output](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40143/missing-a-way-to-filter-debug-output.html) and [Add filtering for OutputDebugString](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/364382/add-filtering-for-outputdebugstring.html), and consider [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) in the meantime.

Comment: this error was when [`DwmGetWindowAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute) called with invalid  *hwnd* - handle to the window and *18000E820* this is address from which `DwmGetWindowAttribute` called. begin from - set breakpoint on this address. who (exe,dll ?) call `DwmGetWindowAttribute`, with what *hwnd*, call stack..

Comment: Is there a sample project file? Cannot reproduce that on my side.

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko - this not depend from any src code/project settings.

Comment: @RbMm I've created a simple C++ Windows Desktop Application. In the MainMenu->About I've added `MessageBox` call as topic started mentioned above. I clicked Menu->About and I do not see that text in the Output window. On my laptop I have Windows 10.0.19042 Build 19042 (20H2)

Comment: @RbMm Here is link to my VS solution: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag3nD_ZwNtVbvQYmlc9E0P97FtdT?e=eWVUTz

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko - again - this not depend from your src code. `MessageBox` by self not produce this error. this is something from operation system settings or error in some version. need research on system where exist such error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `#include <Dwmapi.h>` and now it's not spamming that message in the debug console anymore.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute

I **think** the error was because it was not loading the lib `dwamip.dll`.

Comment: no, the *DwmGetWindowAttribute* inside *dwamip.dll* and call `OutputDebugString` with messages which you view. so this dll was loaded in all case. then simply include header file - not force load any dll and usually have no any effect at all (if no before this compiler errors)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of an [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341), also discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of trying to prevent the messages from being shown, it would be better to prevent them from being generated in the first place.

Judging by the links you posted, this problem has existed for a few years and has bothered many people. Fortunately your first link appears to have a workaround: the post by user "codeviewer" lists a function called `suppress_dwmapi_output()` which when added to your code and called from `InitInstance()` will apparently prevent these messages from being created.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: I already tried that example of `suppress_dwmapi_output()`, the message still appears on the output.

Comment: @Guto It's probably worth saying that in your question. :-)

Comment: @Guto - why you not research error ? why not set bp on *caller: 000000018000E820* and look - which window handle is passed to `DwmGetWindowAttribute` ?

Comment: @RbMm your answer lead me to search more about `DwmGetWindowAttribute` how do I reward you the bounty?

Comment: @Guto if say true - for me unclear how only `#include <Dwmapi.h>` can change result. what is changed in binary ? you not found - why was this error and why it disappear

Comment: I think the error was because it was not loading the lib `dwamip.dll`.

Comment: @Guto - no of course. at first *dwamip.dll* is loaded - the debug output was exactly from this dll. at second simply include header file - nothing change here